# Single paragraph with styling and larger \parskip

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, grouping

I'd like to use something like this:

```
{\bfseries\small Some text here...\setlength{\parskip}{1em}}

More text here in the next paragraph...
```

In order to increase the spacing after a single paragraph, but this doesn't seem to change anything. Is there a right way to do this or do I have to use `\vspace`?

Comment: `\parskip` is inserted at the start of a paragraph; the closing brace resets the value of `\parskip` to what was outside the group. What's the problem with `\vspace`?

Comment: I guess it's fine; it just seemed like `\parskip` would be the natural thing to use for separating paragraphs.

Comment: @jtbandes yes, but changing `\parskip` inside a group makes the change only effective inside that group.

Comment: @jtbandes No, it's not the natural thing. Its use is for uniformly separating paragraphs, not a particular one from another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As **egreg** mentioned in a comment, using `{\bfseries\small Some text here...\setlength{\parskip}{1em}}` won't produce the desired result since the closing brace resets the value of `\parskip` to what was outside the group. You can use one of the predefined skips (`\bigskip`, `\medskip`, `\smallskip`), or `\vspace` (also, don't forget to end the paragraph inside the group to get the correct value for `\baselineskip`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\Text{%
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis.}

\begin{document}

\Text

{\bfseries\small \Text\par}

\vspace{1em}

\Text

{\bfseries\small \Text\par}\bigskip

\Text

\end{document}
```

[image]